# IVRS [Interactive Voice Response System] module in perl?

Tags: perl

Is there any IVRS Perl module avaliable in perl to interact with modem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [Ivrs - Perl extension for Interactive Voice Response System](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Ivrs) what you're looking for?

Simply searched for IVRS on [CPAN.org](http://www.cpan.org/).